# C# DateTime.ToString() is wrong on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 though proper locale is set in current thread

Tags: c#, linux, datetime, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04

Ok this is driving me nuts. I've installed a new instance of a ubuntu 18.04 server which runs my dotnetcore 2.2 mvc application.

Although the locale seems properly set in the OS and in the current thread, the DateTime.ToString() functions give me a wierd data format:

- Wrong format: 19-05-09 12 12 21 21 02 2
- Expected format: 19-05-09 12:21:01

In both case, the current thread local is "fr-CA".
In the OS, the "locale" command returns me "en_US" in both cases.

I've checked depper in the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat and it doesn't seems to be the same in both cases. When looking at the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern variable:

- Wrong format outputs pattern gives me: HH h mm
- Good format server output pattern gives me: HH:mm

What is this sorcery? My nose is bleeding.

Comment: I'm surprised anyone uses `.ToString()` instead of `.ToString(string)` which lets you specify a custom format.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it has been working for 4 years without a hickup. So I'm surprised as why the same locale would produce different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the source code of the DateTime format in the dotnet core, I've came to a fix to ensure the proper working of the ToString() without parameters.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";            
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = ":";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat;
```

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate your results, and it appears to be a specific bug with how .NET Core is interpreting CLDR data for this particular culture.

I reported the issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37557

Answer (score 0):

Like @Powerlord said in comment, why don't you specify the format of your date?

Something like this:

```
DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
```

Output:

```
09-05-19 17:43:10
```

Comment: Because I need a hotfix and I don't have to time to change 10000 references accross the whole applicaiton.

Answer (score 0):

The fix of this issue will be in .NET Core 3.0.

If you want to work around this issue without touching every DateTime.ToString calls, you can try to do something like:

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH 'h' mm 'min' ss 's'"; 
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH 'h' mm"; // or choose whatever format you prefer